# detecting URL and format it in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I would like to be able to format a URL in my UITextField nicely. So say the text of the UITextField is

```
textField.text = @"Hi this is a page for my website http://www.mywebsite.com";
```

I would like it to automatically underline this mark it as a hyperlink and when a user taps on the link it opens up the site. This is similar to any twitter client that you have out there (tweetdeck, tweetbot, etc). How do I do this the easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a UITextView instead and set the dataDetectorTypes property to the types of links you want to be able to handle.

Comment: is there a delegate in which is called when the link is pressed? or how do I handle this?

Comment: @aherlambang: The documentation for dataDetectorTypes states, "When clicked, the text view opens the application responsible for handling the URL type and passes it the URL."

Comment: I just tried this and it seems that it opens up the URL in a full browser window.. what if I want it to open at a UIModalView, how do I do this?

Comment: If you subclass UIApplication, can you intercept the call to `openURL:`? You'd have to determine when openURL is even being invoked first--and it might prove unreliable if the system changes how URLs are opened in the future.

Answer (score 1):

hey this is really simple, you can set the UITextFiled to detect Links, like so:

```
myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll
```

check out my tutorial on this at my site for more info
http://www.sdkboy.com